# how to change english date to spanish in php?

Tags: php, strftime, setlocale

In my project, I have english date saved in database as 'Y-m-d'. Now, I want to show the date in Spanish language in format as 28 May,2015. How am I to do it? I tried the following but to no avail.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
echo utf8_encode(strftime("%d %B, %Y",strtotime($date)));
```

When I print setlocale, it returns bool(false).Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I think simple date and strtotime will solve this

Comment: `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest utilizing the [`intl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) library of functions instead, such as [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php). Which will allow you to output localized data without needing to change the global locale with `setlocale()`.

The Intl library can also allow you to view a list of supported locales you can use `var_dump(ResourceBundle::getLocales(''));`

Example: https://3v4l.org/BKCRo *(notice how `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES')` has no effect on the output.*

```
$esDate = datefmt_create('es_ES', //output locale
    \IntlDateFormatter::FULL, //date type
    \IntlDateFormatter::NONE, //time type
    'America/Los_Angeles', //time zone
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, //calendar type
    'dd LLLL, YYYY'); //output format
echo $esDate->format(new \DateTime);
```

Result:

```
18 diciembre, 2017
```

For a list of supported date format patterns see: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

---

As a note for `setlocale()`, each system is different and not all locales may be supported by your distribution of PHP and server operating system.

When using Linux you can use `locale -a` from a console terminal or `system('locale -a', $locales); var_dump($locales);` from within PHP, to determine supported system locales.

When using Windows you can view the system supported locales by navigating to `Control Panel->Language` or `Control Panel->International Settings`.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx for more details on supported locales for various versions of Windows.

If using `setlocale()` be sure to supply all possible variants in an array of the desired locale, in order of priority from left to right, to reduce the likelihood it will return `false`.

e.g.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, array('es_ES.UTF-8', 'es_ES', 'es-ES', 'es', 'spanish', 'Spanish'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');

// or (to avoid utf8_encode) : setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
echo date("d M, Y", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: An unsupported locale was used in the OP's question, which resulted in a `false` return value as stated in the manual for [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-returnvalues)